# Unique token with form submit doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, forms, token

This is what I want to do:

Prevent a user to submit a form twice using a unique token. I think I have the right code here, but it still dosn't work. The output is "Don't send twice" the first time the form is submitted. What am i doing wrong?

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<body>

<?php

 $_SESSION['token'] = md5(session_id() . time());
?>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
if (isset($_POST['token']))
{
    if ($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token'])
    {
       echo "Don't send twice!"; 
    }
}
}
else {

echo "Thank you for submitting";

} 

?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token'] ?>" />
<input type="text" name="bar" />
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Comment: You create a new $_SESSION['token'] on every page load (the value of "time()" changes constantly), so the condition is always met.

Comment: Redirect to the same page after form is submitted to prevent the form re-submission

Comment: @Rémi I changed the token to...
   $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid());...but I still have the same problem, it says "dont send twice" the first time I submit. Could you show some code example?

Comment: That's not the point. You are re-generating a new session token at every request (whether it's the first GET, or the following POST), thus theses conditions "if (isset($_SESSION['token']))" and
"if ($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token'])" are always true. Only generate a token when one doesn't exist already, and you should start getting better results. Also as the previous comment suggested, to prevent re-submission it's easier to use the [redirect after post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Comment: Ok, tank you, not sure if I know how to create token only if one doesn't exist, but I will try the redirect efter post pattern!

Answer (score 1):

`Thank you for submitting` will never be displayed, because the condition for `if( isset($_SESSION['token']) )` is always fulfilled, because you generate the token and set the session variable directly above this if clause... That's also why you will always see "don't send twice" after submitting the first time.
When loading the form you generate a token, save it in the session, put it in the form.
After submitting the form, you start the script again from the top:
Your token is now in the post variable. But you recreate your session token. then you compare post and session. of course they don't match, because you have just now generated a NEW token, so of course they are not equal.

I recommend this structure for your code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 
session_start(); 

//HAS THE FORM BEEN SUBMITTED?
if(isset($_POST))
{
    //THE FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED

    //VALIDATE THE TOKEN
    if($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])
    {
        //THE TOKEN WAS VALID, CONTINUE WITH PROCEDURES

    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Invalid token, please try again!';
    }

}
else
{
    //FORM NOT SUBMITTED YET

    $token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5( session_id() . time(). rand() ); 
    //i recommend adding rand() otherwise there is always a 1 second window in which the token could be doubled up...

    echo '<form action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] .'" method="post">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'. $token .'" />';
    echo '<input type="text" name="bar" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Save" />';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept here is flawed.

1. Browsers don't let the user submit a form twice using POST. They show an alert to the user telling about the danger to submit the form twice.
2. If the user loads the form twice, this script cannot avoid two submission, because the tokens are different on both forms.

I would suggest to save the submission in the database. This assures that the same session ( or the same user ) can only save one record.

Comment: Very valid point! If it's really just for making sure it doesn't get submitted twice, the token wont help much. 
It is still recommended to use the form tokens to protect yourself against CSRF.