# Form token, to prevent direct access, does not work

Tags: php, ajax, forms, security, token

I want to use a token to secure my pages which are loaded via an AJAX-request (the basic idea is to prevent direct access of that page). So far so good.

The problem is that both tokens do not match. It doesn't work.

To create my token I use this function:

```
function generateFormToken($form) {
$token = md5(uniqid(microtime(), true));

$_SESSION[$form.'_token'] = $token;

return $token;
}
```

To verify them I use this function:

```
function verifyFormToken($form) {
if (!isset($_SESSION[$form.'_token'])) {
    return false;
}

if(!isset($_POST['token'])) {
    return false;
}

if ($_SESSION[$form.'_token'] !== $_POST['token']) {
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

In my form contact_form.php I create my token:

```
$newToken = generateFormToken('contactForm');
```

Then I put that generated token into a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $newToken; ?>" />
```

In my header of my website I start a session:

```
if (session_id() === '') {
    session_start();
}
```

The reason why I'm checking if there's already another session is because on my index.php-page there's a cookie set (without the check I get a PHP-error message saying that there's already a session):

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['ava_lastpage'])) {
$prev_page = secure($_COOKIE['ava_lastpage']);
}
// Set current page
if (!isset($_GET['task']) || (isset($_GET['task']) && $_GET['task'] != 'register' && $_GET['task'] != 'validate' && $_GET['task'] != 'login' && !isset($_GET['status']) || isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] != 'reg_complete')) {
setcookie('ava_lastpage', curPageUrl(), time()+60*60*24*100, '/');
}
```

This is my AJAX-request (contact.php is the file that shall be protected via a token):

```
$.ajax({
type:'POST',
url: '<?php echo $setting['site_url'] .'/';?>includes/misc/contact.php',
data:$('#contactForm').serialize(),

});
```

In my file contact.php I try to validate the token (which doesn't work):

```
if (verifyFormToken('contactForm')) {
      bla bla bla...
```

### Update

The functions mentioned above can be found at [Serious Form Security](http://css-tricks.com/serious-form-security/).

Comment: Start with all the basic debug stuff. 1) check the error_log 2) `print_r($_SESSION); print_r($_POST);` 3) Open FireBug and check the AJAX request request/response headers to see what the cookies are doing.

Comment: On my page contact.php I do not have access to my token of the superglobal $_SESSION. There's nothing...

Comment: Check to make sure the cookie is set. Download FireFox, install Firebug, then check the "cookies" tab and "NET" tab to see the headers that set the cookies.

Comment: The cookie is set. That was one of the first things I checked. BTW: It seems to work now - the structure of my site was the problem. Everytime when I requested contact.php a new token was created so this was the reason why they didn't match! This topic helped a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412648/unique-token-with-form-submit-doesnt-seem-to-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should change the header of your website to:

`session_start();`

Comment: I already did this and then I get an error message saying that there's already a session (via cookie).

Comment: Is `session_start()` also called in contact.php?

Comment: No. I added it in contact.php and now I get a different token. That's the reason why it doesn't work. When I'm echo'ing both tokens on the form they are equal (surprise surprise) but on the file contact.php the token $_SESSION['contactForm_token'] is different. Do I have to generate the token on my form or at my index.php right under session_start(); ?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the session variables only after the session_start() call.

Comment: Uhm...it seems to work now. That's because I changed the structure of my site. Just curious: Do I have to check if the token already exists BEFORE I create a new one?

Comment: It might be useful to check if you want to know whether the user actually submitted the form (you will have to unset the token in the verifying method), otherwise you can simply overwrite it.

Comment: I have a javascript-function which loads my form. Where do I have to put the token? Inside of the form OR inside of my header / index.php?

I'm wondering if it's more secure to generate it inside of my header and then pass it as a parameter to a javascript-function which loads my form (the form gets opened via modal pop-up window).

Comment: Do you generate the form with javascript on the client-side or do you load it from the server?